# PHP.ini file changes are not taking effect

Tags: php, web

My website is getting the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found

I fixed this on my localhost (XAMP) by uncommenting the line:

```
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

This worked for localhost. Now I have put the website onto a Linux server with GoDaddy, but I get the same error.

I have put the same *php.ini* file from my localhost into the root server and ran [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), which confirms the loaded configuration file is coming from the correct *php.ini* file.

So I know that my *php.ini* settings are correct, and I know that the website is loading the correct *php.ini* file - why is it still not working?

Comment: Have you restart the server ?

Comment: It's a shared, not dedicated - is that possible?

Comment: _“I have put the same php.ini file from my localhost into the root server”_ – that of course doesn’t work; a linux system is hardly going to execute any `.dll` files. As per http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php, this extension is included in PHP5 by default, but it has to be activated via a switch at PHP compile time. Ergo: You can not enable this yourself in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: If it's really a shared server, they won't let you even see the php.ini file, much less edit it. Your only solution is to ask them politely if they can install the extension for you. Or find a better host that can.

Comment: @CBroe If you put a php.ini file in the root folder with godaddy it overrides the other one and uses that, its the only way to edit.

Comment: you can override a lot of php.ini settings in hostgator too, they have a pretty crappy system. However this only works on virtualized hosting not on your average 1$ shared webhost

Answer (score -2):

You can add extensions the "PHP version" tab in the [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel). It's not very clear that it's there, but it works. I found this out by calling them.